# カレントディレクトリの変更方法

Tags: python, python3

こんにちは　初めて質問させていただきます。
初心者のため、ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

これでカレントディレクトリがわかって
`C:\\Users\\○○\\Documents\\surasura-python\\chapter05`
と表示されました。そこでこのカレントディレクトリを変更しようと
`os.chdir('C:\\Users\\○○\\Documents\\surasura-python\\')`
と打って変更はできたのですが`quit()`でインタラクティブシェルを閉じると
`C:\\Users\\○○\\Documents\\surasura-python\\chapter05`　と元にもどってしまいます。
どうしたら変更をしたままにできますか？

Comment: 参考:[Pythonでディレクトリを移動した状態で終了したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18132)

Comment: 質問にある"import os"などのコマンドを入力している画面(アプリケーション)は、どのようにして起動しましたか？　起動されたアプリケーションは何ですか？　コマンドプロンプトなら起動直後は 環境変数のHOMEDRIVEとHOMEPATHに基づいたディレクトリになります(HOMEDRIVEが"C:"で、HOMEPATHが"\Users\○○"なら C:\Users\○○ がコマンドプロンプト起動時のディレクトリになります）

Answer (score 2):

できません。

仮に、なんらかの方法で出来たとしても、一般的に使える方法ではないと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それでは追加でお聞きしたいのですが、カレントディレクトリを変更したままにできないのであればどういう状況でos.chdirを使うことになりますか？

Comment: 当該 python を起動したシェルと python 自体は別プロセスです。カレントディレクトリとはプロセスごとにあるものなので、実行中の python プログラムのカレントディレクトリを変更する目的で os.chdir を使うことができます。呼び出し元のシェルのカレントディレクトリを変更することは os.chdir ではできなくて、別の方法が必要です（コメントリンク先参照）

Comment: Pythonの中で open('/path/to/file1'), open('/path/to/file2'), ... などを繰り返す場合、 os.chdir('/path/to') したあと open('file1'), open('file2'), ... と実行できます。